# Dominated Convergence Theorem for random variables

Tags: probability

I have $X_n \to X$ a.s and $E[X_n^2] \leq c$ How do I prove with the dominated convergence theorem that $E[X_n] \to E[X]$? I already  have one of the hypotheses of the theorem, we can only see that $|X_n| <\phi$ Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "I already have one of the hypotheses of the theorem" and "we can only see that $|X_n|\leq \phi$" ?  What is $\phi$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the sequence $\{X_n\}$ is bounded in $L^2$, it follows that $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, for if $A$ is an event with $\mathbb{P}(A)<\delta$ then
$$ \mathbb{E}[|X_n|1_A]\leq \mathbb{E}[X_n^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbb{P}(A)^{\frac{1}{2}}< \sqrt{c\delta} $$
for all $n$.

Next, since $X_n\to X$ a.s. we can conclude that $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$ by the [Vitali convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem).

Thanks to @Michael for the correction.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer... very friendly!

Comment: What form of dominated convergence theorem are you using here?  Typical LDC requires $|X_n|\leq Y$ for all $n$ and for an integrable $Y$.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, good point. I guess uniform integrability should be used instead. Let me edit...

Comment: That would work, though I wonder what assumptions/results the asker is allowed to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof (note that it is sufficient to assume convergence in probability).

\begin{align*} E[ |X_n -X| ] &=E[|X_n-X|,|X_n-X|<\epsilon]+E [ |X_n -X|,|X_n-X|\ge \epsilon]\\
& \le \epsilon + (E [ |X_n-X|^2])^{1/2} P(|X_n-X|\ge \epsilon)^{1/2}=(*)
\end{align*} 
(second summand on second line due to Cauchy-Schwarz).

Now $|a+b|^2 \le 2a^2+2b^2$ therefore $|X_n-X|^2 \le 2 X_n^2 + 2X^2$. Also by Fatou, $c \ge \liminf E[|X_n|^2] \ge E[|X|^2]$. Therefore

$$(*) \le \epsilon + (4c)^{1/2} P(|X_n -X|>\epsilon)^{1/2}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to} \epsilon+0.$$

Result follows since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

" Como $\xi_n \rightarrow \xi$ casi seguramente, entonces se puede definir un conjunto $A$, tal que para todo $A\in F$, $P(A)<\delta$ y $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \xi_n(w)=\xi, \ \forall \omega\in A$.\
Luego por la desigualdad de Cauchy-Schwarz se tiene que:
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\vert \xi_n 1_A\vert &\leq& (E\xi_n^2 E(1_A)^2)^{1/2}\\
&=&(E\xi_n^2 P(A)^2)^{1/2}\\
&\leq& \sqrt{c\delta}, \ \forall n
\end{eqnarray*}
Por lo tanto  $E\xi$ es finita.

Por otro lado
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\vert \int_{A} \xi_n d P -\int_{A} \xi d P \right\vert &\leq & \int_{A} \vert \xi_n -\xi\vert d P \hspace{0.5cm} \ \exists N\in N \mid \forall n\geq N \\
 &\leq & \int_{A} \epsilon d P  =\epsilon.
 \end{eqnarray*}
 Dando lo deseado. "

So?